# Función en php para calcular total de horas de un rango de fechas dada una semana y un intervalo de tiempos

Tags: php, date, datetime, timestamp, time

Estoy intentando crear una función en php que, dados unos rangos de fechas y horas (datetime), me determine la cantidad de horas entre esos rangos que pertenecen a una semana del año en específico, teniendo en cuenta unos intervalos entre horas y sólo si el total de horas para esa semana es mayor que 48. Los intervalos entre horas para el conteo son:

```
desde las 00:00 hasta las 06:00 y desde las 22:00 hasta las 23:59.
```

Hasta el momento sólo he podido contar el total de horas para cada rango de fechas dado usando:

```
function cuentaHorasRango($sube,$baja)
{
    $datetime1 = new DateTime($sube);
    $datetime2 = new DateTime($baja);
    $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
    return $interval->format('%H');
};
```

Pero no he podido saber cómo hacer el conteo con la restricciones de la semana específica del año, que el total de horas de esa semana sea mayor a 48 y los intervalos entre horas.

Por ejemplo: Suponiendo que tenemos los siguientes intervalos de fecha dados:

```
Subida: 2017-01-02 02:00 - Bajada: 2017-01-03 21:00
Subida: 2017-01-07 03:48 - Bajada: 2017-01-10 19:48
```

Y que la semana del año dada es la semana 1, entonces tendríamos las siguientes consideraciones:

```
    A.Contar el total de horas entre los rangos que pertenezcan a la semana y verificar si es mayor a 48. 

    B.Luego para 2017-01-02 02:00 hasta 2017-01-03 21:00 tendríamos que ese rango sí pertenece a la semana 1 del año 2017 y el total de horas entre ese rango es 43.

    C.Para 2017-01-07 03:48 hasta 2017-01-10 19:48, tenemos que los días 7 y 8 sólo son los que pertenecen a la semana 1 por lo que el rango que debemos tener en cuenta sería de 2017-01-07 03:48 hasta 2017-01-08 23:59(¿ó 24:00 ?). El total de horas entonces para ese rango es 44.

    D. Como 43+44=87>48, entonces la función debe hacer el conteo de horas teniendo en cuenta los intervalos así: 
    Rango 2017-01-02 02:00 hasta 2017-01-03 21:00: el dia 2017-01-02 el total de horas que van desde 00:00 hasta 06:00 es 4; el total de horas que van desde 22:00 hasta 23:59 es 2. El día 2017-01-03, el total de horas que van desde 00:00 hasta 06:00 es 6; el total de horas que van desde 22:00 hasta 23:59 es 0 
Es decir, el valor devuelto por la función en ese rango debe ser 4+2+6=12.
```

Está un poco complicada la cuestión pero cualquier ayuda o guía que me puedan brindar sería de mucha utilidad para mí, ya que en estos momentos me encuentro totalmente estancado.

Mil gracias de antemano por su tiempo.

Saludos,

Reginaldo

Comment: El mismo `DateTime` que utilizas puede devolverte la semana del año a la que pertenece esa fecha, puedes hacer un agrupamiento de las fechas por la semana del año a la que pertenecen y calcular precisamente las horas. Checa esta referencia https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9567673/get-week-number-in-the-year-from-a-date-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para hacer el conteo de horas entre semanas hay que considerar lo siguiente

Resultado del día de la semana al utilizar el llamado `format('w');`

```
| L | M | M | J | V | S | D |
|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 0 |
```

Dado cualquier día de la semana(número del día):

1. Para llegar al final de esa semana(Domingo) debemos contar los días entre medias incluyendo al Domingo, cuando el día elegido sea el domingo no sumaremos días. Se incluirán las horas para llegar hasta **23:59:59**.
2. Para ir al inicio de esa semana(Lunes), hay que restar al día actual 1, con excepción del Domingo que debemos restar 6. E iremos desde **00:00:00**

El orden de los días está de esta forma, ya que el número de semana empieza a correr desde los Lunes(ISO 8601).

Dicho esto la solución podría quedar de la siguiente forma

```
<?php 
function hoursInInterval($datetime1, $datetime2, $interval)
{
    $daysDiff = $interval->format('%d');
    $initialHour =      $datetime1->format('G');
    $initialMinute =    $datetime1->format('i');
    $finalHour =        $datetime2->format('G');
    $finalMinute =      $datetime2->format('i');
    $sumaHoras = 0;

    if($daysDiff == 0) {
        if(($initialHour < 6 && $finalHour < 6) || ($initialHour > 21 && $finalHour > 21) || ($initialHour > 21 && $finalHour < 6)) {
            $sumaHoras += $interval->format('%H') + ($interval->format('%i') / 60);
        } else {
            if($initialHour < 6) {
                $sumaHoras += 5 - $initialHour + ((60 - $initialMinute)/60);
            } elseif($initialHour > 21){
                $sumaHoras += ($initialHour - 22) + ($initialHour/60);
            }

            if($finalHour > 21) {
                $sumaHoras += ($finalHour - 22) + ($finalMinute/60);
            }elseif($finalHour < 6){
                $sumaHoras += 6 - (5 - $finalHour) + ((60 - $finalMinute)/60);
            }
        }

    } else {
        $sumaHoras = 8 * $daysDiff;
        if ($initialHour != $finalHour) {
            if($initialHour < 6){
                $sumaHoras += 5 - $initialHour + ((60 - $initialMinute)/60);
            } else {
                if($initialHour > 21){
                    $sumaHoras += ($initialHour - 22) + ($initialHour/60);
                }
            }

            if($finalHour < 6){
                if($finalHour < $initialHour)
                    $sumaHoras += 1 + (6 - (5 - $finalHour)) + ((60 - (60-$finalMinute))/60);
                else
                    $sumaHoras += 6 - $finalHour + ((60 - $finalMinute)/60);
            } else {
                if($finalHour > 21){
                    $sumaHoras += ($finalHour - 22) + ($finalMinute/60);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $sumaHoras;
}
function horasPorSemana($sube,$baja)
{
    $datetime1 = new DateTime($sube);
    $datetime2 = new DateTime($baja);

    $week1 = $datetime1->format('W');
    $week2 = $datetime2->format('W');

    if($week1 == $week2) {
        // Ambas fechas caen en la misma semana
        $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
        // print_r($interval);
        $response[$week1]['horas'] = ($interval->format('%d') * 24) + $interval->format('%H') + ($interval->format('%i') / 60);
        $response[$week1]['horas_intervalo'] = hoursInInterval($datetime1, $datetime2, $interval);

    } else {
        // Las fechas caen en diferente semana
        // día de la semana de la primera fecha
        $dayOfWeek1 = $datetime1->format('w');
        // día de la semana de la segunda fecha
        $dayOfWeek2 = $datetime2->format('w');
        // obtenemos las horas de la primera semana
        $endWeek1 = clone $datetime1;
        if($dayOfWeek1 != 0) {
            // se agrega un día al cálculo de la primera semana debido a que al obtener el número de semana(date('W')) toma en cuenta a partir de los lunes y el número de día de la semana(date('w')) comienza el domingo
            // si lo dejaramos calculando normal desde el domingo, las horas de ese domingo se irian a la segunda semana, cuando deberían de pertenecer a la primera
            $endWeek1->add(new DateInterval('P'.(7-$dayOfWeek1).'D'));
        }
        $endWeek1->setTime(23, 59, 59);
        $hoursWeek1 = $datetime1->diff($endWeek1);

        // obtenemos horas de la última semana
        $startWeek2 = clone $datetime2;
        if($dayOfWeek2 == 0) {
            $startWeek2->sub(new DateInterval('P6D'));
        } else {
            // removemos el día agregado al calculo de horas de la primera semana
            $startWeek2->sub(new DateInterval('P'.($dayOfWeek2-1).'D'));
        }
        $startWeek2->setTime(0, 0, 0);
        $hoursWeek2 = $startWeek2->diff($datetime2);

        $response[$week1]['horas'] = ($hoursWeek1->format('%d') * 24) + $hoursWeek1->format('%H') + ($hoursWeek1->format('%i') / 60);
        $response[$week1]['horas_intervalo'] = hoursInInterval($datetime1, $endWeek1, $hoursWeek1);

        for($i=$week1 +1; $i < $week2; $i++) {
            $response[str_pad($i, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT)]['horas'] = 7*24;
            $response[str_pad($i, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT)]['horas_intervalo'] = 7*8;
        }
        $response[$week2]['horas'] = ($hoursWeek2->format('%d') * 24) + $hoursWeek2->format('%H') + ($hoursWeek2->format('%i') / 60);
        $response[$week2]['horas_intervalo'] = hoursInInterval($startWeek2, $datetime2, $hoursWeek2);
    }
    return $response;
}

$rangos = [
    ['Subida' => '2017-01-02 02:00', 'Bajada' => '2017-01-03 21:00'],
    ['Subida' => '2017-01-07 03:48', 'Bajada' => '2017-01-10 19:48'],
    // ['Subida' => '2018-03-03 00:00', 'Bajada' => '2018-03-05 00:00'],
];
// el número de semana debe llevar ceros al principio en caso de ser menor a 10, lo rellenaremos con 0's a la izquierda a longitud 2
// el primer parámetro es el número de la semana
$numeroSemana = str_pad(1, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
$sumaHoras = 0;
$resultados = [];
foreach ($rangos as $rango) {
    $resultado = horasPorSemana($rango['Subida'], $rango['Bajada']);
    if(isset($resultado[$numeroSemana])) {
        $sumaHoras += $resultado[$numeroSemana]['horas_intervalo'];
    }
    $resultados[] = $resultado;
}
print_r($resultados);
if($sumaHoras > 48) {
    echo "Hay más de 48 horas en la semana {$numeroSemana}";
}
```

Comment: Gracias Hammerffall BK. Funciona perfecto para calcular las horas totales por semana. ¿Cómo se le añade la funcionalidad de contar sólo las horas x semana que cumplan con los intervalos mencionados (desde las 00:00 hasta las 06:00 y desde las 22:00 hasta las 23:59)?

Comment: Eso no lo entiendo, por ejemplo cuando explicas el cálculo de `2017-01-02 02:00 hasta 2017-01-03 21:00` dices que son 43 horas cuando en realidad según tu lógica debería de ser 11 (del día 2 seria 4h en la mañana, 1hr en la noche, y del día 3 serian 6h en la mañana)

Comment: Es correcto, tenía un error en el ejemplo. 43 sería el TOTAL de horas en ese rango, pero sólo para tenerlo en cuenta para la sumatoria de horas totales en esa semana (para después verificar que sean>48). Para el conteo de horas entre intervalos sería: el día 2017-01-02 02:00 y hasta ese dia a las 23:59 tendríamos que para el intervalo de 00:00 a 06:00 = 4 horas y el intervalo de 22:00 a 23:59 =2 horas; Para el día 2017-01-03 desde las 00:00 y hasta las 21:00 tendríamos que para el intervalo 00:00 a 06:00 = 6 horas y para el intervalo 22:00 a 23:59 = 0 horas. El valor devuelto sería 12 horas.

Comment: Puedes checar con la edición que agregué.

Comment: Gracias Hammerffall BK. Funciona perfecto, solo que para la parte de la sumatoria de horas debe ser  $sumaHoras += $resultado[$numeroSemana]['horas'] en vez de $sumaHoras += $resultado[$numeroSemana]['horas_intervalo'].

Comment: Una consulta adicional, y disculpame el abuso: Si quisiera restringir el conteo de las horas entre intervalos para que comience a partir del momento en que se cumpla la condición del total de horas x semana>48, ¿cómo podría se podría hacer?. y de manera opcional (posiblemente especificando otro parámetro) que la función no incluya en el conteo total los domingos.

Comment: Que comience el conteo desde que se cumpla las 48 por semana, de todos modos necesitas el conteo. Necesitas hacer un recorrido de día por día y ver si cae día domingo, por ejemplo `$datetime1->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));` verificar si `format('w') == 0`, calcular en el intervalo de 00:00:00 a 23:59:59 o hasta el final en caso que hayas llegado al final del intervalo.